# Nginx Using AWS Auto Scaling Group instances in configuration files with Nginx open source

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, aws-auto-scaling

I want to add the servers which are behind the AWS Auto Scaling Group to the Nginx configuration file , I see with Nginx plus there is an agent nginx-asg-sync which we can use directly and it will do the work .

Is there any possibility that we can use the same in Nginx open source service ? , I am using Nginx open source and I am not finding a way to come up from this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in AWS you only need to know how CLI/API works.
you can build this agent using only two cli commands:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names {PARAMS}
```

where {PARAMS} you query auto scaling group name and get instances IDs from it.

the second command is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids {PARAMS}
```

then all you have to do is to build all the logic around this, for example in bash script you create nginx upstream template, and everytime new instance was launched you compare ip addresses and swap upstreams and reload nginx. or you can simply add/delete ip with `sed`

here is more eamples how you can do this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/704806/how-to-get-autoscaling-group-instances-ip-adresses

also you can add health check before changing upstreams.